# Failed to establish route, since neither were provided: 'spring.cloud.function.definition'

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud-function

I have a problem with a lambda project in java, when the elements arrive to the queue, the lambda consumes them and when they are going to enter the lambda this error comes up

```
Failed to establish route, since neither were provided: 'spring.cloud.function.definition' as Message header or as application property or 'spring.cloud.function.routing-expression' as application property. Incoming message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[973], headers={aws-context=lambdainternal.api.LambdaContext@13b29b34, id=7e00385d-ff52-2e7e-0a6a-c68df012c679, timestamp=1685986732788}]: java.lang.IllegalStateException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to establish route, since neither were provided: 'spring.cloud.function.definition' as Message header or as application property or 'spring.cloud.function.routing-expression' as application property. Incoming message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[973], headers={aws-context=lambdainternal.api.LambdaContext@13b29b34, id=7e00385d-ff52-2e7e-0a6a-c68df012c679, timestamp=1685986732788}]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.RoutingFunction.route(RoutingFunction.java:156)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.config.RoutingFunction.apply(RoutingFunction.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:710)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:562)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker.handleRequest(FunctionInvoker.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)*
```

Comment: The error says you need to provide configuration parameters that were not provided.

Comment: what parameters and where?

Comment: The error says you need to either set `spring.cloud.function.definition` or `spring.cloud.function.routing-expression`. If you're using spring boot, docs for configuration can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: The error message could not have been more clear `since neither were provided: 'spring.cloud.function.definition' as Message header or as application property or 'spring.cloud.function.routing-expression' as application property.` as well as documentation - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_routing